# Create a CSV file with VBA without the empty columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-to-csv

**Situation:** Working on an excel tool for which I need to save files as .csv on a shared folder through the below code:

```
Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        "FILEPATH&NAME ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

**Problem:** The files created through this method are very large (20,046 Ko) and slowing down everything (saving for the user and excel queries afterwards).
This seems to stem from the fact that it's saving thousands of empty columns when my files are supposed to be only 27 columns.

**What I've tried:** I've tried to save as CSV instead, there's the same issue of size.

How can I code it to create a file without the empty columns and rows?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you press Ctrl+End on the worksheet, does it select a cell a long way past the end of your data?

Comment: No, but I get an alert
"Wee looked at all your data next to your selection and didn't see a pattern for filling in values for you. To use flash fill, enter a couple of examples of the output you'd like to see, keep the active cell in the column you want filled in, and click the flash fill button again"

Comment: The flash fill shortcut key is Ctrl+E, not Ctrl+End.

Comment: oups read too fast my bad! Ctrl+End gets me to cell XEZ1253 - so for sure where the issue is coming from -> how do i fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: Delete all rows and columns after the end of the actual data, then save the workbook and test it again.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's 1Ko - just need to know how to code so VBA does that for me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not xlText, but xlCSV.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet
    'Wb.SaveAs Filename:="myTest.text", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Ws.SaveAs Filename:="myTest.text", FileFormat:=xlCSV

End Sub
```

Comment: The code I shared was for the .txt try I did indeed.
I used your code above with same results, the file geenrated is still 20,046 Ko unfortunately.
But when I reopen these files, re-save as .csv manually, they do get to a regular .csv size - but I cannot do this as I'm trying to automate the process and get 100+ files per week.